# My Dell V715w Printer won't communicate with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing

I've been trying to get this printer to work for days, to no avail. The make and model is the Lexmark Pro710 Series. The system sees the printer; it shows up in available printers, but nothing happens when I try to actually print a document. When I go to document print statuses, it describes the printer state as "processing - sending data to printer."

The printer works fine on Win10, but on 16.04, nothing. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows, if so make sure it shuts down completely (fast boot should not be working) before accessing the printer on Ubuntu.